# Using shapes with flex in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I am trying to write text in a circle in react native, however the circle needs to fit into a certain location using flex. Is this something that is possible? As when I try to do it the shape always get malformed into kind of a semicircle with a rectangle attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Example Image]
https://rnplay.org/apps/OolZWQ

I threw together an example of this and it seems to be working fine for me.

```
    <View style={styles.someLocation}>
      <View style={styles.circle}>
        <Text>Test</Text>  
      </View>
    </View>
```

Perhaps compare yours against mine?   Be sure to enforce the size of your circle and there should be no overriding style that can change that.

```
  circle: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    borderRadius: 100/2,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  someLocation: {
    backgroundColor: '#0f0',
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
    padding: 10
  }
```